# Changing model field within the Django Shell

Tags: python, django, shell, field, models

Is there anyway to use the Django shell to modify a field value? I can create, delete, and query models, but I don't know how to alter existing field values.

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Game, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the Django shell, I try `Game.objects.get(name="testb").likes = 5`, but it still outputs `likes = 0` when I input `Game.objects.get(name="testb").likes` right afterwards.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should save the changes,

```
game = Game.objects.get(name="testb")
game.likes = 5
game.save()
```

Comment: That was much simpler than I thought it would be...

Thanks for the help, works perfectly

Answer (score 7):

Calling `Game.objects.get()` retrieves the data from the database.

When you execute the statement `Game.objects.get(name='test').likes = 5`, you are retrieving the data from the database, creating a python object, and then setting a field on that object in memory.

Then, when you run `Game.objects.get(name='test')` again, you are re-pulling the data from the database and loading a python object into memory. Note that above, when you set `likes` to `5`, you did that purely in memory and never saved the data to the database. This is why when you re-pull the data, `likes` is `0`.

If you want the data to be persisted, you have to call `game.save()` after setting the `likes` field. This will enter the data into the database, so that the next time you retrieve it via `.get()`, your changes will have persisted.

Answer (score 1):

If u need change all fields for all items, just try this:

```
from shop.models import Product


Product.objects.filter(recommend=True).update(recommend=False)
```

U can use this in Django Shell. Have a nice time :)